# Magento2: How to change order status for COD orders

Tags: magento2

Currently

- when customer pay order in advance example in paypal I have order status "paid".
- when customer try pay for order in advance example via paypal but payment refused I have order status "pending".
- But when customer select payment method "Cash on Delivery" I also have order status "pending".

How to set:
When customer select payment method "cash on delivery" then default status order is "COD".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can follow Magento official docs to add a new order status
   https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-status-custom.html
2. Then you can assign new order status in Payment setting
   [image]

Comment: It won't be there by default. You need to create a new status, assign the new status to the Pending group, then it will appear as expected.